# String operations on a sequence

Tags: xslt

I have an XML that contains a series of images and their widths:

```
<p>
    <image width="10cm"/>
    <image width="3cm"/>
</p>
```

I need to calculate the total width of these images. 
When I have only 1 image, this is simple:

```
<template match="p">
    <xsl:variable name="imgwidth">
        <xsl:value-of select="number(substring-before(image/@width,'cm'))"/>
```

Naively, I tried expanding this to accommodate more images:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(number(substring-before(image/@width,'cm')))"/>
```

When I run this on my sample, I get an error message:

> A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of   fn:substring-before() ("10cm", "3cm")

I've done some searches, but can't figure out how to run the substring-before on each image node inside my `<p>`.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 or 3.0?

Comment: yes, stylesheet is already using XSLT 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you can write this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(image/number(substring-before(@width,'cm')))"/>
```

Or, perhaps this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(for $i in image return number(substring-before($i/@width, 'cm')))"/>
```

Comment: That simple, huh? I've been going off on all kinds of tangents looking at fn:sequence, etc.